# how to batch dealing with files using Goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

Assuming I have a bunch of files to deal with(say 1000 or more), first they should be processed by function `A()`, function `A()` will generate a file, then this file will be processed by B().

If we do it one by one, that's too slow, so I'm thinking process 5 files at a time using goroutine(we can not process too much at a time cause the CPU cannot bear).

I'm a newbie in golang, I'm not sure if my thought is correct, I think the function `A()` is a producer and the function `B()` is a consumer, function `B()` will deal with the file that produced by function `A()`, and I wrote some code below, forgive me, I really don't know how to write the code, can anyone give me a help? Thank you in advance!

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var Box = make(chan string, 1024)

func A(file string) {
    fmt.Println(file, "is processing in func A()...")
    fileGenByA := "/path/to/fileGenByA1"
    Box <- fileGenByA
}

func B(file string) {
    fmt.Println(file, "is processing in func B()...")
}

func main() {
    // assuming that this is the file list read from a directory
    fileList := []string{
        "/path/to/file1",
        "/path/to/file2",
        "/path/to/file3",
    }

    // it seems I can't do this, because fileList may have 1000 or more file
    for _, v := range fileList {
        go A(v)
    }

    // can I do this?
    for file := range Box {
        go B(file)
    }
}
```

**Update:**

sorry, maybe I haven’t made myself clear, actually the file generated by function `A()` is stored in the hard disk(generated by a command line tool, I just simple execute it using `exec.Command()`), not in a variable(the memory), so it doesn't have to be passed to function `B()` immediately.

I think there are 2 approach:

approach1
[image: approach1]

approach2
[image: approach2]

Actually I prefer approach2, as you can see, the first `B()` doesn't have to process the file1GenByA, it's the same for `B()` to process any file in the box, because file1GenByA may generated after file2GenByA(maybe the file is larger so it takes more time).

Answer (score 4):

You could spawn 5 goroutines that read from a work channel. That way you have at all times 5 goroutines running and don't need to batch them so that you have to wait until 5 are finished to start the next 5.

```golang
func main() {
    stack := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}

    work := make(chan string)
    results := make(chan string)

    // create worker 5 goroutines
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for s := range work {
                results <- B(A(s))
            }
        }()
    }

    // send the work to the workers
    // this happens in a goroutine in order
    // to not block the main function, once
    // all 5 workers are busy
    go func() {
        for _, s := range stack {
           // could read the file from disk
           // here and pass a pointer to the file
            work <- s
        }
        // close the work channel after
        // all the work has been send
        close(work)

        // wait for the workers to finish
        // then close the results channel
        wg.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    // collect the results
    // the iteration stops if the results
    // channel is closed and the last value
    // has been received
    for result := range results {
        // could write the file to disk
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/K-KVX4LEEoK

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have another thought, can you take a look of my update, I prefer approach2. And another question is: can we don't wait for the 5 goroutines to finish? I mean if 1 is finished, can we dynamically add 1 to let it up to 5?

Comment: @Willis, while they don't *have* to run serially, there is no benefit in adding the overhead of writing and reading from disk in-between A and B and synchronizing this. As long as 5 workers are working, you are happy, doesn't matter on what they are working. Might as well pass the file in memory around. To your second question, with this approach 5 workers run constantly until no more work is left, at all. So you don't need to create a new goroutine when one finishes. When one finishes you know all files have been processed or at least the last 4 remaining files are currently being processed.

Comment: @Willis, if you really want, you should be able with the given concepts to implement the behaviour yourself. Either by using a second channel or by sending the processor along with the filename in the same channel. You can use a struct containing the filename and processor as fields.

Comment: "there is no benefit in adding the overhead of writing and reading from disk in-between A and B" - yep, but actually the file is not generated by my go code, it's generated by a "command line tool"(I just simple executing it using `exec.Command()`).

Comment: @Willis, there is still no benefit in separating the processing via  A and B. If 5 workers a busy, 5 workers are busy, it doesn't matter with what. What do you gain by separating those?

Answer (score 2):

you're halfway there.  There's a few things you need to fix:

1. [your program](https://go.dev/play/p/lglBpwzfE0f) deadlocks because nothing closes `Box`, so the main function can never get done `range`ing over it.
2. You aren't waiting for your goroutines to finish, and there than 5 goroutines.  (The solutions to these are too intertwined to describe them separately)

#### 1. Deadlock

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
```

When you `range` over a channel, you read each value from the channel until it is *both closed and empty*.  Since you never `close` the channel, the `range` over that channel can never complete, and the program can never finish.

This is a fairly easy problem to solve in your case: we just need to close the channel when we know there will be no more writes to the channel.

```
    for _, v := range fileList {
        go A(v)
    }
    close(Box)
```

Keep in mind that `close`ing a channel doesn't stop it from being *read*, only *written*.  Now consumers can distinguish between an empty channel that may receive more data in the future, and an empty channel that will never receive more data.

Once you add the `close(Box)`, the program doesn't deadlock anymore, but it still doesn't work.

#### 2. Too Many Goroutines and not waiting for them to complete

To run a certain maximum number of concurrent executions, instead of creating a goroutine for each input, create the goroutines in a "worker pool":

- Create a channel to pass the workers their work
- Create a channel for the goroutines to return their results, if any
- Start the number of goroutines you want
- Start at least one additional goroutine to either dispatch work or collect the result, so you don't have to try doing both from the main goroutine
- use a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for all data to be processed
- `close` the channels to signal to the workers and the results collector that their channels are done being filled.

Before we get into the implementation, let's talk aobut how `A` and `B` interact.

> first they should be processed by function A(), function A() will generate a file, then this file will be processed by B().

`A()` and `B()` must, then, execute serially.  They can still pass their data through a channel, but since their execution must be serial, it does nothing for you.  Simpler is to run them sequentially in the workers. For that, we'll need to change `A()` to either call `B`, or to return the path for `B` and the worker can call.  I choose the latter.

```
func A(file string) string {
    fmt.Println(file, "is processing in func A()...")
    fileGenByA := "/path/to/fileGenByA1"
    return fileGenByA
}
```

Before we write our worker function, we also must consider the result of `B`.  Currently, `B` returns nothing.  In the real world, unless `B()` cannot fail, you would at least want to either return the error, or at least `panic`.  I'll skip over collecting results for now.

Now we can write our worker function.

```
func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, incoming <-chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for file := range incoming {
        B(A(file))
    }
}
```

Now all we have to do is start 5 such workers, write the incoming files to the channel, close it, and `wg.Wait()` for the workers to complete.

```
    incoming_work := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(&wg, incoming_work)
    }
    for _, v := range fileList {
        incoming_work <- v
    }
    close(incoming_work)
    wg.Wait()
```

Full example at https://go.dev/play/p/A1H4ArD2LD8

#### Returning Results.

It's all well and good to be able to kick off goroutines and wait for them to complete.  But what if you need results back from your goroutines?  In all but the simplest of cases, you would at least want to know if files failed to process so you could investigate the errors.

We have only 5 workers, but we have many files, so we have many results.  Each worker will have to return several results.  So, another channel.  It's usually worth defining a `struct` for your return:

```
type result struct {
  file string
  err error
}
```

This tells us not just whether there was an error but also clearly defines which file from which the error resulted.

How will we test an error case in our current code?  In your example, `B` always gets the same value from `A`.  If we add `A`'s incoming file name to the path it passes to `B`, we can mock an error based on a substring.  My mocked error will be that `file3` fails.

```
func A(file string) string {
    fmt.Println(file, "is processing in func A()...")
    fileGenByA := "/path/to/fileGenByA1/" + file
    return fileGenByA
}

func B(file string) (r result) {
    r.file = file
    fmt.Println(file, "is processing in func B()...")
    if strings.Contains(file, "file3") {
        r.err = fmt.Errorf("Test error")
    }
    return
}
```

Our workers will be sending results, but we need to collect them somewhere. `main()` is busy dispatching work to the workers, blocking on its write to `incoming_work` when the workers are all busy.  So the simplest place to collect the results is another goroutine.  Our results collector goroutine has to read from a results channel, print out errors for debugging, and the return the total number of failures so our program can return a final exit status indicating overall success or failure.

```
    failures_chan := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        var failures int
        for result := range results {
            if result.err != nil {
                failures++
                fmt.Printf("File %s failed: %s", result.file, result.err.Error())
            }
        }
        failures_chan <- failures

    }()
```

Now we have another channel to close, and it's important we close it *after* all workers are done.  So we `close(results)` after we `wg.Wait()` for the workers.

```
    close(incoming_work)
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)
    if failures := <-failures_chan; failures > 0 {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

Putting all that together, we end up with [this code](https://go.dev/play/p/OZaNn75ZPa7):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func A(file string) string {
    fmt.Println(file, "is processing in func A()...")
    fileGenByA := "/path/to/fileGenByA1/" + file
    return fileGenByA
}

func B(file string) (r result) {
    r.file = file
    fmt.Println(file, "is processing in func B()...")
    if strings.Contains(file, "file3") {
        r.err = fmt.Errorf("Test error")
    }
    return
}

func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, incoming <-chan string, results chan<- result) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for file := range incoming {
        results <- B(A(file))
    }
}

type result struct {
    file string
    err  error
}

func main() {
    // assuming that this is the file list read from a directory
    fileList := []string{
        "/path/to/file1",
        "/path/to/file2",
        "/path/to/file3",
    }
    incoming_work := make(chan string)
    results := make(chan result)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(&wg, incoming_work, results)
    }
    failures_chan := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        var failures int
        for result := range results {
            if result.err != nil {
                failures++
                fmt.Printf("File %s failed: %s", result.file, result.err.Error())
            }
        }
        failures_chan <- failures

    }()
    for _, v := range fileList {
        incoming_work <- v
    }
    close(incoming_work)
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)
    if failures := <-failures_chan; failures > 0 {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

And when we run it, we get:

```
/path/to/file1 is processing in func A()...
/path/to/fileGenByA1//path/to/file1 is processing in func B()...
/path/to/file2 is processing in func A()...
/path/to/fileGenByA1//path/to/file2 is processing in func B()...
/path/to/file3 is processing in func A()...
/path/to/fileGenByA1//path/to/file3 is processing in func B()...
File /path/to/fileGenByA1//path/to/file3 failed: Test error
Program exited.
```

#### A final thought: buffered channels.

There is nothing wrong with buffered channels.  Especially if you know the overall size of incoming work and results, buffered channels can obviate the results collector goroutine because you can allocate a buffered channel big enough to hold all results.  However, I think it's more straightforward to understand this pattern if the channels are unbuffered.  The key takeaway is that you don't *need* to know the number of incoming or outgoing results, which could indeed be different numbers or based on something that can't be predetermined.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have different opinion, this line `results <- B(A(file))` in the worker function, I don't think the file generated by `A()` should return to `B()` immediately, because the file is stored in the hard disk, and we can put the file path to the channel, function `B()` can process it from the channel at anytime, they doesn't have to be run serially, something like: worker A1 produced product1(file1), worker A2 produced product2(file2), but product1 doesn't have to be buy by consumer B1, it could be buy by consumer B2 too, I hope I've made myself clear.

Comment: I've update my question, I prefer approach 2, but I don't know how to write the code.

Comment: They *do* have to be run serially, in the sense that A must be done writing the file to disk before B can process that file from disk.  But you're right, you could pass this data with a channel instead.  You'll want to add another worker pool for `B`, another channel between `A` and `B`, and you'll need to `close` the channel and use a `sync.WaitGroup` to `Wait()` for `B`'s workers to complete.  Since it doesn't really buy you anything, it's just additional complexity